# Use graphql-java-extended-scalars with Quarkus

Tags: java, graphql, quarkus, graphql-java

I want to use `ExtendedScalars.Json` from the `graphql-java-extended-scalars` package in my application which utilizes the `quarkus-smallrye-graphql` however I am struggling doing so.

Given a Test model class like

```
public class Test {
  public String name;
  public Object description;
}
```

with following `GraphQLApi`

```
@GraphQLApi
public class API {
  @Inject
  SomeService someService;

  @Query
  public Test getTest() {
    return someService.getTest();
  }
}
```

where `Test` might be described by

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": {
    "hello": "world"
  }
}
```

the field `description` should be treated as `ExtendedScalars.Json`, so the result of this GraphQL query

```
{
  test {
    description
  }
}
```

should be exactly

```
{
  "data": {
    "test": {
      "description": {
        "hello": "world"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However the `@ToScalar` annotation does not take `ExtendedScalars.Json` and falling back to `graphql-java` with something like `public GraphQLSchema.Builder addScalar(@Observes GraphQLSchema.Builder builder) { ... }` to manually replace the Type and QueryType leads to a AssertException like

> graphql.AssertException: All types within a GraphQL schema must have unique names. No two provided types may have the same name.
> No provided type may have a name which conflicts with any built in types (including Scalar and Introspection types).
> You have redefined the type 'Query' from being a 'GraphQLObjectType' to a 'GraphQLObjectType'

Any clue how to handle this?

Comment: hi @greenmover, can you share me how you did apply `graphql-java-extended-scalars` into quarkus?

Comment: Hi @TinNguyen, I wish I could. Unfortunately it did not work for me. However there is a chance that they fixed this with Quarkus 2.1.

Comment: Great to know. Do you have the detail how to fix it on Quarkus 2.1? Thanks

Comment: I'm using `2.1.0.Final` version. Not sure what version they fixed this